# Why are there two Eiffel Towers?

Tags: april-and-the-extraordinary-world

In the alternate history steampunk world depicted in [April and the Extraordinary World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_and_the_Extraordinary_World) the [(Second?) French Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_French_Empire) is more powerful and longer lasting than the one that existed in the non-fictional timeline.  This is apparently largely due to the French Empire avoiding a conflict with [Prussia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussia) as a side-effect of the untimely explosive death of [Napoleon III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon_III) during the film's introduction.  This is consistent with the work's theme of a world frozen technologically and politically in many ways.

One of the many other side-effects of a resurgent French Empire is the appearance of a second [Eiffel Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_Tower) in [Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris), right next to and identical to the real Eiffel Tower of history.

[image: The two Eiffel Towers on the movie cover]

Is there some reason given in the film or hinted at in history that explains why the second Eiffel Tower was built?

> At the end of the movie, we learn that the launch pad for the Lizards' spaceborne missile is deep beneath the second Eiffel Tower and the second tower is destroyed during the launch of the missile, symbolizing a return to normal political and technological development.  But it doesn't appear to explain why or how the second Eiffel Tower was built or what the reasoning behind it is (unless its purely symbolic).

Why are there two Eiffel Towers?

Comment: To use it as an aerial tramway station ?

Comment: "How can we make France look even more prosperous?" -- "I know!-- they build *two* Eiffel Towers!"

Comment: @errantlinguist: "hence twice more tourists!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the film's director, the twin Eiffel Towers were designed to serve as the gantry for an extensive cable car terminus.

> **Q.**  *How did you come up with the magical idea for the “cruise liner”
>   suspended on cables that April’s parents used to run away? Are you
>   fascinated by those often far-fetched prototype vehicles that have been
>   invented throughout all periods of history?*
>
> ***I have to say that it was our cowriter Benjamin Legrand who came up with
>   the idea for the Paris-Berlin cable car link, with the double Eiffel
>   Tower serving as a terminus in the French capital.*** We’ve all seen the
>   Eiffel Tower but the cable car had to be invented, so I went through
>   some back issues of “La Science et la Vie” from the beginning of the
>   century, and found some descriptions of several fascinating mechanical
>   prototypes. I also used old diagrams of steam engines and other inspired
>   contraptions because I wanted the cable car to be credible. It had to be
>   steam-powered, the mechanisms had to turn the wheels using a method
>   similar to that of a bicycle chain, and it all had to work using rack
>   and pinion. It took me quite a long time to make it realistic. And
>   although you can’t really see how it works, I also designed its internal mechanisms. I think the cable car works well in the film, and that you believe in it.
>
> <sub><sup>[INTERVIEW WITH BENJAMIN LEGRAND - CO-WRITER](https://julianwhiting.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/english-language-notes-to-april-and-the-extraordinary-world.pdf)</sup></sub>

You might wish to note that all the evidence suggests this isn't a *second Eiffel Tower built next to the original and then converted into a skyway terminus* but that the two towers were built together for that express purpose.